# convert charSequence elements into enum elements

Tags: java, android, enums, charsequence

In AndroidStudio , I've made a list containing colors to select from using `AlertDialog.builder`.
I stored the colors in charSequence like this `CharSequence colors[] = new CharSequence[] {"Red1" , "Green1", "Blue1"};`
so far so good.
Now I've made a class `object1` that has an enum `Color` defined like this

```
     public class Object1 {
          public enum Color {
            Red, Green, Blue
        }
          private Color selectedColor;
          public Object1 (Color color) {
          this.selectedColor = color;
          }
    }
```

I want that whenever a color is selected from the AlertDialog a new instance of Object1 will be created with color chosen from the AlertDialog. meaning I need a way to convert charSequence  into matching Color element (enum) and passed to objecgt1 constructor. How can I do this? I need to convert `"Green1"` for example into `Object1.Color.Green` I don't this that the `ValueOf` method will help here since `Green` and `Green1` are different Strings Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following to get enum object from a given String.

```
public class Object1{

     public static enum Color {
        RED("Red1"), GREEN("Green1"), BLUE("Blue1");

        private String type;

        Color(String type) {
            this.type = type;
        }

        public String getType() {
            return type;
        }

        public static Color fromString(String text) {
            if (text != null) {
                for (Color color : Color.values()) {
                    if (text.equalsIgnoreCase(color.type)) {
                        return color;
                    }
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Now if you call

```
Object1.Color type = Object1.Color.fromString("Green1");
```

It will return you an enum of 'GREEN' type.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to map the String values to the enum names. This can be done as easy as the following:

```
public static Color getColor(String name) {
    String mappedName = name.substring(0, name.length() - 1);
    return Color.valueOf(mappedName);
}
```

But it totally depends on your only logic, so just try to map it depending on your real implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add something to translate your char sequences to Colors. I would recommend using a static map:

```
  private static Map<CharSequence, Color> charsToColors;
  static
  {
    charsToColors = new HashMap<>();
    charsToColors.put("Red1", Color.Red);
    charsToColors.put("Green1", Color.Blue);
    charsToColors.put("Blue1", Color.Green);
  }
```

Then when you need the Color for the CharSequence you could get it like so:

```
charsToColors.get("Red1")
```

As tynn said there are other ways to do this too, you just need to pick the one that best fits your use case.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I chose

Comment: Glad to hear it helped :D